# reading remote images in ssh server with matlab

Tags: image, matlab, ssh

Is it possible to read an image in a remote server with ssh in a matlab code?

I mean, I want to do this, but Matlab is not allowing:

```
image_file=strcat('sftp://user@ssh_server/user/images/image_name.tif');
imread(image_file);
```

I can login in this ssh server without password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are on linux/unix, you can use `scp` from matlab to fetch the file, e.g.

```
!scp username@localhost:/tmp/source/test.png /tmp/ 
% please note ! at the beginning.
```

This will prompt you for password offcourse. Thus, if you want, you can setup public-key authentication for [passwordless](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/) scp command.